# Qual è il significato di "fare macchia contro" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> L'immagine si presentava appunto, nell'insieme, d'un color
>   plumbeo e funesto, per entro il quale, nondimeno, se ne scorgevano confusamente altri, quello delle carni, delle vesti, dei monili: deboli parvenze di colori. Essa non era peraltro trasparente, e
>   oscurò un grande quadro sulla parete a me opposta, il quale prima
>   vi **faceva macchia contro**. Pareva, infine, dotata di luce propria,
>   poiché se ne distinguevano agevolmente i particolari malgrado
>   l'estrema incertezza della visione nella stanza.

Ho cercato il termine "macchia" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "faceva macchia contro" in questo brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Credo che significhi che il quadro appeso alla parete fosse più scuro della parete stessa, e risaltasse come una macchia.